# Python Black hooks (language: system)

Tags: python, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com, python-black

I am using black on pre-commit
and this is the hook

```
- repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 19.10b0
    hooks:
      - id: black
```

this is the CI config I am using for black

```
 black --check .
```

and it will reformat some files in the pre-commit
and make it fails when build the project on CI

```
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0007_auto_20190616_0310.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0011_auto_20190620_0517.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0020_auto_20191030_0712.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0021_auto_20191106_0013.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0026_delete_comparison.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0004_auto_20190613_1032.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0005_auto_20190614_0405.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/views/session.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore_api_server/logger.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore_api_server/settings/base.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore_api_server/settings/local.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/models.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore_api_server/settings/production.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore_api_server/settings/test.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/migrations/0001_initial.py
reformatted /Users/rzuhairi/Documents/Anymotion/encore-api-server/encore/tests/serializers/test_drawing.py
All done! ✨  ✨
16 files reformatted, 119 files left unchanged.
```

and then when I change the hooks into this

```
- repo: https://github.com/psf/black
    rev: 19.10b0
    hooks:
      - id: black
        language: system
        language_version: python3
```

it will not reformat the files

I have 2 questions about this:

1. what is this hooks means: 'language: system' because when I read the
   documentation it should be `language: python`?
2. is anyone know why my
   first hook didn't work, and black in my pre-commit keep
   auto-updating my files?

Comment: what's the output of `black --version`?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity it's `20.8b1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what is this hooks means: 'language: system' because when I read the documentation it should be language: python?

This means it'll just use whatever `black` points to on your system, instead of creating a new virtualenv.

> is anyone know why my first hook didn't work, and black in my pre-commit keep auto-updating my files?

No, but my best guess is you're using a different version of `black`. What's the output of `black --version`?

Comment: specifically it means whatever version of `black` you have on your `system` is not the same as the configured version (19.10b0)

Comment: @AnthonySottile thank you very much for the answer
thank you very much for the explanation black --version output is `black, version 20.8b1` it is not the same with the hook

Comment: @ignoring_black  even tho I installed the same version and change the hooks, it keeps modifying my files